# Stub Calls to `Aws.config.update()`

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, aws-sdk, stub

I am writing unit tests (using the Ruby MiniTest framework) for a class which, as part of the constructor, configures the AWS SDK global configuration with a set of credentials.

It does so by calling `Aws.config.update()` and passing a hash of credentials.

As part of the test I do not want this configuration change to take place. Is there any way I can achieve this without modifying the class being tested? ie Without adding in a condition to the method call driven by a method parameter.

Whilst this doesn't seem like a 'stub' scenario (I don't want a canned response in return from the call, I just don't want that call to result in a configuration change) I wondered if I could use the AWS SDK stubbing capabilities (described quite nicely [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/stubbing-aws-responses/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stubbing without specifying a return value has the effect you intend, for example:

```
expect(Aws.config).to receive(:update)
```

afer this, running `Aws.config.update` will just return nil and not actually run anything. You could also use `allow`.

You didn't specify what testing library you're using, but to be clear the example I gave is in RSpec.

Comment: Thanks @max-pleaner I have updated the question to clarify the test framework I am using, which is `MiniTest`. So I guess the equivalent would be to create a `MiniTest::Mock` object and add an expect, like so?

`mock = MiniTest.Mock.new()`
`mock.expect(:update, nil, [{}])`

And then stub the `Aws.config` call like this?

`Aws.config.stub(:update, mock)`